# How to get the desired dictionary result using mutable arrays in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I  have three mutable array:

1. wkdatearray values like this: date from 2016-01-10 to 2016-01-16.
2. spentonarray values like this: 2016-01-10 to 2016-01-13.
3. hoursarray values like this: 7,3,4,5,1.

So, I compare the index objects of wkdatearray and spentarray like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.wkDateArray.count; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < self.spentonArray.count; j++) {
  if ([
    [self.wkDateArray objectAtIndex: i] isEqualToString: [self.spentonArray objectAtIndex: j]
   ]) {

   NSLog(@ "Matched Indexes %d %@", i, [self.wkDateArray objectAtIndex: i]);
  } else {

  }
 }
```

Now I want to get the result like :

If the index value of self.wkdatearray and self.spentonarray are matched or equals then I have to set the hours array value as object for self.wkdatearray[0],[1]…[6]. like this in newsheet  dictionary. Now I manually put string @"".

```
newSheet = [NSDictionarydictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:strEntryID,entryID, proj,project,projID,projectId, strIssue,issue,strIssueID,issueId, strActivity,activity,strActivityId,activityId,@"",comment,@"",self.wkDateArray[0],@"",self.wkDateArray[1],@"",self.wkDateArray[2],@"",self.wkDateArray[3],@"",self.wkDateArray[4],@"",self.wkDateArray[5],@"",self.wkDateArray[6], nil];
```

If the index value of self.wkdatearray and self.spentonarray are not matched and not equals then the hours value like this @“‘ as object for self.wkdatearray[0].like this in newsheet dictionary. Now, I put by default object values as @""for self.wkdatearray[0...6].

Here the hours array having 5 values only.

How to do both the conditions inside the for loop? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Rob  sir please help me on this sir

Comment: @Etienne sir how to do this sir.help me sir.

Comment: any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make the newSheet dictionary mutable. You do not need 2 for loops.

```
int minIndexCount = MIN(self.wkdatearray.count, self. spentonArray.count)
```

we first take the min of `wkdatearray.count` and `spentonArray.count` since for example if there are only 2 items in `spentonArray` then if we try to use index 4 of `wkdatearray` then we do not have index 4 in `spentonArray`, meaning the primary condition that the indexes of both `wkdatearray` and `spentonArray` should be equal fails. Hence by taking min we ensure that we are only going to compare those indexes whixha re available in both `wkdatearray` and `spentonArray`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < minIndexCount; i++) {
   if ([[self.wkDateArray objectAtIndex: i] isEqualToString: [self.spentonArray objectAtIndex: i]]) 
   {

      NSLog(@ "Matched Indexes %d %@", i, [self.wkDateArray objectAt Index: i]);
      [newSheet setValue:self.hoursarray[i] forKey:self.weekArray[i]]

   } else {

   }
}
```

Comment: on else part what i have to put sir.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <7; i++)
 {if([[self.spentonArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{
self.hoursArray1[i] = @"";
 }
if ([[self.wkDateArray objectAtIndex: i] isEqualToString: [self.spentonArray objectAtIndex: i]])
                        {
                        self.hoursArray1[i] = hours;
                        }
                        }

Comment: here wkstartdate from 2016-01-31  to 2016-02-05 where spentonarray from  2016-01-31 to 2016-02-04 on comparing indexes it throughs error.index beyond ...so  i have to check the spent array index null if it is null.ihave to assign this value self.hoursarray[i]=@"'; how to put the condition correctly

Answer (score 0):

If by "matched or equals" you mean that if the index's are the same AND the strings are matched.

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.wkDateArray.count; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < self.spentonArray.count; j++) {
  if (i==j && [
    [self.wkDateArray objectAtIndex: i] isEqualToString: [self.spentonArray objectAtIndex: j]
   ]) {

   NSLog(@ "Matched Indexes %d %@", i, [self.wkDateArray objectAtIndex: i]);
  } else {

  }
 }
```

Take note of the beginning of the if statement that has `if (i==j && ...`